# run additional logic besides [Authorize] annotation

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, adal

I'm using the **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer** and **System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt** for my .NET Core project.

Whenever I generate a new token I store that to the database. When a user signs out, I remove it from the database to invalidate it (I also remove the expired ones from the database with a job). When a user tries to access a route protected by the `[Authorize]` annotation I want to check if that token exists in the database. If not, I send a 401.

In my *Startup* in the `Configure` method I'm calling `app.UseAuthentication()` and in the `ConfigureServices` method I setup the validation for the `[Authorize]` annotation (I tried to comment it to show what I want to achieve)

```
services
.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddJwtBearer(jwtBearerOptions =>
{
    byte[] symmetricKey = Convert.FromBase64String("secretFromConfig");
    SymmetricSecurityKey symmetricSecurityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(symmetricKey);
                    
    jwtBearerOptions.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
    {
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        ValidateIssuer = false,
        ValidateAudience = false,
        IssuerSigningKey = symmetricSecurityKey,
    };

    jwtBearerOptions.Events = new JwtBearerEvents()
    {
        OnTokenValidated = tokenValidatedContext =>
        {
            // inject my database repository
            ITokensRepository tokensRepository = tokenValidatedContext.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ITokensRepository>();
            JwtSecurityTokenHandler tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
                            
            // convert the token to a string
            string token = tokenHandler.WriteToken(tokenValidatedContext.SecurityToken);
                        
            // read the username from the token payload
            Claim usernameClaim = tokenValidatedContext.Principal.Claims.FirstOrDefault(claim => claim.Type == "username");
                            
            // assign if exists
            string username = usernameClaim?.Value;
                   
            // fetch token from database         
            object tokenInfo = await tokensRepository.GetUserTokenAsync(token, username);
                            
            if (tokenInfo == null)
            {
                // return a 401 if token doesn't exist in database
                tokenValidatedContext.Fail("Invalid token.");
                // return new UnauthorizedResult();
            }
            else
            {
                tokenValidatedContext.Success();
                                
                // controller methods can fetch it from here later on
                tokenValidatedContext.HttpContext.Items["username"] = username;
            }
                    
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    };
});
```

When I try to make the `OnTokenValidated` callback async for the repository call I get the error message

> Return type is 'void'

How can I solve it? The callback has to be async because I'm accessing the database. Any help will highly appreciated!

Comment: You could try to modify the JwtBearerEvents to this: `OnTokenValidated = async tokenValidatedContext =>`

Answer (score 2):

I believe one of the better ways to do this is through adding a policy to your Authorization. (Similar to how it is handled if you want to create a claims policy)

If you want the policy only for certain authorize tage

**Startup.cs**

```
 services.AddAuthorization(authorizationOptions =>
 {
    authorizationOptions.AddPolicy(
    "MustHaveTokenInDb",
    policyBuilder =>
    {
       //add any other policy requirements here too including ones by default
       //eg policyBuilder.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
        policyBuilder.AddRequirements(
            new MustHaveTokenInDbRequirement());
    });
    //only if you want to register as the default policy
    authorizationOptions.DefaultPolicy = authorizationOptions.GetPolicy("MustHaveTokenInDb");
});
```

Then in the authorize

Tag you use

```
[Authorize("MustHaveTokenInDB")]
```

You can set a default policy either which allows you to use the Authorize tag as normal

```
authorizationOptions.DefaultPolicy = authorizationOptions.GetPolicy("MustHaveTokenInDb");
```

**Your requirement class**

```
public class MustHaveTokenInDbRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement
    {
        public MustHaveTokenInDbRequirement ()
        {
        }
    }
```

**Handler class**

```
 public class MustHaveTokenInDbHandler : AuthorizationHandler<MustHaveTokenInDbRequirement >
    {

        public MustHaveTokenInDbHandler ()
        {
            //your dependency injections
        }

        protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(
            AuthorizationHandlerContext context, 
            MustHaveTokenInDbRequirement requirement)
        {  
           //your logic
            if (noTokenInDb)
            {
                context.Fail();
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }


            // has token in db
            context.Succeed(requirement);
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
```

In your configure services you need to register it:

```
services.AddScoped<IAuthorizationHandler, MustHaveTokenInDbHandler>();
```

Comment: thanks for your reply! I updated my question, I think I found a better solution :)

Comment: that's an interesting solution, especially if you want to add in an extra check that you know won't change across across the scope of the API. The main reason I like the approach in my answer is that it is very flexible, you can stack policies, or only run a policy on certain requests. If you have a new Authorization claim to check you can really easily add it in. If you have a dynamic Authorization policy that can change a lot or that requires different claims for different requests I would recommend an approach similar to in my answer.